# Xcode 10.2: Internal error when debugging app

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, simulator

When I tried to run my app it could not launch on simulator or device, while throwing error.

> Could not Launch "Carepilot" internal error

So I try Edit

```
sheme -> run -> info -> Debug executable
```

to make sure the Debug executable option is not checked, debug mode is disabled there, but this can't be debugged.

Anyone encountered same problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why you're seeing that, but here are some basic debugging steps to try.

First, turn debugging back on, you'll want that. Any solution that doesn't let you debug is useless.

Second, quit Xcode and and quit the Simulator. Sometimes things get in a funky state. Relaunch Xcode and try again.

If it still happens, reboot. Try again.

If it still happens, try it with a new project to rule out any issues with yours.

If it still happens, go to Xcode>Preferences…>Locations`, do you have Xcode 10.2 (10E125) command line tools installed and selected? That's what you should see.

If that's not it, go to the Terminal and enter `xcode-select -p`. Does the path displayed point to the `Contents/Developer` directory under your Xcode app? If not, set that using `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` (substituting your Xcode app's name if necessary).

Unfortunately, "internal errors" in Xcode occur for various reasons and don't provide any useful information. If all else fails, you may need to try reinstalling.

Comment: Great job, your suggestion solves my issue successfully, "If it still happens, reboot. Try again.", this step is work, thanks again!

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue after an Xcode crash. Turns out that the executable no longer existed after the crash, but Xcode continued to access it since the reference still existed. Because of this, receiving this exact error is common when trying to debug the build.

If you click on the executable reference in the Products folder you can get the full path for the old build executable from the inspector on the right. Where  is the name of your project, this path should be something like this:

`/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<projectname>-<randomhash>/Build/Products/Debug/<projectname>`

With the offending path in mind, you can open a terminal, change to the DerivedData folder, and remove the build folder.

```
$ cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
$ rm -r project-randomhash
```

After removing the build folder, re-build your project and debug once again.